# Chrome Auto Login - Deprecation Passing 'PasswordCredential' objects into 'fetch - howto solve?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, credentials

Hi we have been using the following flow to trigger a custom Chrome logon event if the customer is known. Recently we have run into this warning.

`(index):1259 [Deprecation] Passing 'PasswordCredential' objects into 'fetch(..., { credentials: ... })' is deprecated, and will be removed in M62, around October 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5689327799500800 for more details and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/credential-management-updates for migration suggestions.`

We use the following to logon the customer.

**My question is**: 1) how can we mitigate/solve the above 'Deprecation' issue? And 2) is there a more native/standard method to ask for a confirmation to logon? (pref. in the users own browser language)

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e) {
    var debug = false;
    var _waitandaskagain = 1800;
    var start = new Date()
    var _askforconfirmation = false;
    var cookie_name = "smartlock_cancel_cookie";
    var smartlock_cancel_cookie = getCookie(cookie_name);
    if (smartlock_cancel_cookie) {
     return
    } else {
        navigator.credentials.get({
            password: true,
        }).then(function(cred) {
            if (cred) {
                if (cred.type == 'password') {
                    var form = new FormData();
                    cred.additionalData = form;
                    cred.additionalData.append("form_key", "SECRET");
                    var url = 'https://ourdomain.com/webcustomer/account/loginpostgoogle/';
                    if (_askforconfirmation && confirm('Logon to the website securely? Please Confirm')) {
                        fetch(url, {
                            method: 'POST',
                            credentials: cred
                        }).then(function(response) {
                            if (response.status == 202) {
                                if (debug) {
                                    console.log('Login success; reloading now');
                                    return;
                                }
                                navigator.credentials.store(cred);
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                            if (debug) {
                                console.log('Server status: ' + response.status);
                            }
                            return;
                        }).catch(function(err) {
                            console.log('Smartlock Ajax error:' + err.message);
                        }).then(always, always);
                    } else {
                        expiry.setDate(start.getDate() + (_waitandaskagain));
                        document.cookie = cookie_name+"=true; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else if (typeof cred === "undefined") {
                var end = new Date();
                if (+end >= (+start + 100)) {
                    if (debug) {
                        console.log('Manual cancel detected - too slow');
                    }
                    expiry.setDate(start.getDate() + (_waitandaskagain));
                    document.cookie = cookie_name+"=true; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
                }
                if (debug) {
                    console.log('Credentials undefined');
                }
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not send credential object in the fetch, instead manually append to the form (or JSON),  object things from the credential Object

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: cred // NO
}

// example with JSON
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      pass: cred.password,
      id: cred.id,
      "form_key": "SECRET"
    })
}
```

2) There is no standard in this regard, UX is completly up to you